# How do I emit a call to String.op_Equality in Mono.Cecil

Tags: .net, reflection, il, mono.cecil

I'm trying to inject code into an assembly using Mono.Cecil. So far it's all been great but now I'm trying to implement this bit of IL:

```
call bool [mscorlib]System.String::op_Equality(string, string)
```

How do I do this in Cecil? I know it's something like

```
var il=mymethod.Body.GetIlProcessor();
...
il.Emit(Opcodes.Call, ????);
```

I don't know what kind of parameter to send in or how to get a reference to that static function.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
MethodReference ope = myMainModule.Import(typeof(string).GetMethod("op_Equality"));
il.Emit(Opcodes.Call, ope);
```